# How to ignore 'server-only' when running from cli

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, tsx

I have a NextJS app which contains a library which I want to make sure is not imported on the client. I do this with `import 'server-only'`, but I also want to use this file for a local script. Yet when I run `tsx scripts/test.ts` I get the server components error.

How can I ensure a library is not imported on the client?

My folder structure is:

```
 - app
   - ...
 - lib
   - server-only-library.ts
 - scripts
   - local-script.ts
```

Files:

```
# server-only-library.ts
import 'server-only'
...
```

```
# local-script.ts
import Library from 'lib/server-only-library'
...
```

Test:

```
$ tsx scripts/local-script.ts
/Users/michael/my-app/node_modules/server-only/index.js:1
throw new Error(
      ^
Error: This module cannot be imported from a Client Component module. It should only be used from a Server Component.
```

I have tried to map it using webpack, but the error will then only appear on the client during runtime and not during build time.

```
# next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  // doesn't work :( the import is mapped, but only throws in runtime
  webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        '@secret/library': 'next/../server-only',
      }
    }
    return config
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar challenge in my Next.js projects, needing to restrict certain imports to server components and CLI scripts. To address this, I developed an NPM package named `server-cli-only`. Unlike `server-only`, allowing imports in Next.js server components and CLI environments. This solution should enable you to use your `server-only-library.ts` in server components and `scripts/local-script.ts` in the CLI without import errors.

### Installation

First, install the package via npm:

```bash
npm i server-cli-only
```

### Usage

In Next.js server components, place this import at the top of your server-only-library.ts:

```js
import "server-cli-only";
// Your server-side code follows...
```

For local scripts like `scripts/local-script.ts`, set the `RUNNING_IN_CLI` environment variable to `true`. This signals `server-cli-only` to allow the import and not throw an error:

```bash
RUNNING_IN_CLI=true tsx scripts/local-script.ts
```

### More Info

- NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/server-cli-only
- Source Code: https://github.com/destacks/core-ts/tree/main/packages/server-cli-only

### **Edit:** Internal Working (Optional)

The `server-cli-only` package is tailored for React Server Components and CLI environments, safeguarding against its inclusion in client-side components.

- **React Server Environments:** Utilizes an empty module (`./empty.js`) in environments specified by the `"react-server"` environment. For more details, see [RFC #227](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0227-server-module-conventions.md).
- **CLI Environments:** In Node.js contexts (`"node"` in `"default"` export environments), it checks if `RUNNING_IN_CLI` is set to `"true"`. If not, it throws an error, guiding for correct CLI usage.
- **Client Component Environments:** In browser contexts (`"browser"` in `"default"` export environments), `./index.js` throws an error to always prevent usage in client-side rendering.

This configuration tries to align with the guidelines in the React Server Module Conventions of [RFC #227](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0227-server-module-conventions.md) but slightly extends them to enable script use on the CLI.

Comment: Interesting approach, but you're using try/catch for logic which is an anti-pattern. The server-only package uses exports from package.json to import the file based on the environment, code here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/server-only?activeTab=code, details explained here: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0227-server-module-conventions.md.

I believe this can be solved by specifying "browser" vs "node" in the exports, instead of just having the same file for both.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Michael Ozeryansky. I adjusted my implementation, but was able to maintain the core mechanics, using `import "server-cli-only"` and `RUNNING_IN_CLI=true tsx scripts/local-script.ts`, but changed the code better align with RFC #227 by updating `package.json` to include "react-server", "default", "browser", and "node" exports. I've removed using try/catch for control flow. I also updated my original answer to reflect these changes.